# How to sync between log files between linux and windows machines?

Tags: linux, windows, rsync

I have 20 linux servers on which some of the microservices are deployed and they keep genrating some logs on respective servers.
All the servers are on same network and have connectivity between all of them.
I have a **windows machine** which runs a log analytics program.
So I want all my logs to be get synced and consolidated in the single file in real time  on this windows machine.
How can I do this?

Comment: I'd use rsyslog to aggregate all the logs on a linux machine and then mount that over NFS or Samba to the Windows machine.

Answer (score 3):

**You could use Filebeat on your 20 Linux servers in combination with Logstash on your Windows machine.**

- [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) is a data processing pipeline that lets you ingest any log file. It helps you to receive logs from multiple sources, transform them, and save them wherever you like. There are a lot of [output plugins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/output-plugins.html), maybe even one for the log analytics software in use on your Windows machine.
- [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat), on the other hand, helps you to forward and centralize log files.

Both tools are built by [Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/) and work great together.